# Происходит ли неявный каст к указателю на функцию при вызове функции?

Tags: c++, функции, language-lawyer

При вызове функции происходит неявный каст к указателю на функцию и разыменование?

```
#include <iostream>

int g() {
    std::cout << "1";
    return 1;
}

int main()
{

    g(); //здесь происходит неявный каст к указателю на функцию и разыменование?
}
```

Comment: приведите код, на который у вас вопрос.

Comment: Было бы странно добавлять взятие адреса и сразу разыменовывание. Но вообще, непонятно, какая разница. Если очень хочется, можно раскопать в стандарте.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Сомневаюсь, что в стандарте описано, как реализовывать то или иное действие...

Comment: @Harry Там может быть написано, есть ли автоматическое взятие адресе/разыменовывание, или функция напрямую вызывается. Но разница в любом случае только в названии, поэтому я и удивляюсь такому вопросу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Не думаю — это может быть сильно привязано к архитектуре. Не уверен, но даже механизм виртуальных вызовов через vtable, кажется, в стандарте не описан... Как и реализация ссылок, например.

Comment: Нет, в C++ при вызове функции *function-to-pointer* преобразования не происходит в отличие от C.

Comment: Простой способ самому разобраться с подобными вопросами, это трансяция с получением ассемблера, например `g++ -S ...` (или дизассемблирование объектного файла, например [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump)-ом)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В стандарте С++ указано, что *function-to-pointer* преобразования в случае вызова функции нет.

[[expr.call]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.call#1):

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses
> containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of
> *initializer-clause*s which constitute the arguments to the function. ... **For a call to a non-member function** <strike>or to a static
> member function</strike>, the postfix expression shall either be an
> lvalue that refers to a function (in which case **the
> function-to-pointer standard conversion**
> ([[conv.func]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/conv.func))
> **is suppressed** on the postfix expression), <strike>or have function pointer type</strike>.

В отличие от C, где преобразование будет.

[[6.5.2.2]/1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf):

> **Constraints**
>
> The expression that denotes the called function<sup>106)</sup> shall
> have type pointer to function returning
> `void` or returning a complete object type other than an array type.
>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> <sup><sup>106)</sup>Most often, this is the result of converting an identifier that is a function designator.</sup>

[[6.3.2.1]/4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf):

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type.
> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`
> operator<sup>71)</sup>, a typeof operator, or the unary & operator, a
> function designator with type "function returning *type*" is converted
> to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*".
> ...

---

Преобразование в C++ будет в местах, где ожидается *prvalue*, а также в некоторых других контекстах, где это явно прописано стандартом.

[[basic.lval]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.lval#6):

> Whenever a glvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the *lvalue-to-rvalue*, *array-to-pointer*, or *function-to-pointer* standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue. ...

Например, в выражении `(*g)();` уже будет преобразование (не при вызове).

[[expr.unary.op]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary *** operator performs *indirection*: **the expression to
> which it is applied shall be** a pointer to an object type, or **a
> pointer to a function type** and the result is an lvalue referring to
> the object or function to which the expression points.

Однако стоит отметить, что обычно преобразования категорий выражений (чтение значения переменной, преобразования массива/функции в указатель) происходят только на уровне языка и [не влияют на генерируемый код](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BXIFVNQJ1DQTFkTFxibb1jc25bcM9faXliQCUtqhexMjsHGEEANT8qBBzmyYA7FYaAIKbF5vEmATLDJuSZib%2BJ6dHACImZ1%2BnG5ssTDCewOxx%2BlyuNzumwgACo4Ts5sDrNtULs5s9Xh8OAtaJwErw/BwtKRUJw3NZkQolitMAczP4eKQCJpsQsANaJDT6TiSXgsEAMgB0/gAnGYNJIEpLpVKEoFCcTSRxeAoQFzmUTsaQ4LAYIgUKgWMk6HFyJQ0EaTfFgFwzGZSFgAG54VYANTwmAA7gB5ZKMTiMmi0AhxVUQaIs0jRMINACeAd4FrYgm9DFo8c1DswAKM4kz%2BGuNUdmFVmcwqmqXhDCfIgkwuMztDw0WIcY8WEjBGIeH53C1VAMwAU7q9vv9fZkghEYnYUkn8iUakjui4%2BkMxgpln0zdVkAWqGSjgEpYAtAoCOhnu9TJZrOLNifvcSOke/BBXGNWkEGOhpgN4quqTpK%2Bn56EBhQMH%2BZSDKuL61CMTSeC0ehwV0CFQbMsEIaBWFTGE/TQQBCxUssqwSDieIEpGSqbKoAAcABsJ4MZImzAMgyCbLagpmNCuCECQdIMnMvAalocwLAgmBMFg8R7KQHIJFyDa8qQ/JKaQCq8EqKpqkyLILDq%2BoWsa9BkBQEAmVaKAGEYXBKVyToupgI4%2Bn6hKBnQIbEGGEaZtGzDEBmjJJowBCpumkZYDmwB5sSBbVI4xalsS5aVtWE4bPWkZNi2bYYGsxJdj2CYLAOTBDq5Y4ebw/BTqI4hznVC4qOoma6PatkbreW65bu8kHq%2Bp7npe/jXpuFj3o%2Bz71olmQuD%2BOHfr%2B%2BEzDB%2BTAZkS3ga%2BGHrahDDdKMSHjLYs2dId6Grf%2BKHYSdX7nnhJQ3VwxHUmRr3chw%2BKadRnC0YxzGscgXVcQkgoaBDfH4EQxBCa9okGZJ0myZQ7Kcl9qlaSSnC6eqSNfWYfIgAxdGCgxGiHCKsoypKSTYzp%2BmahJCkSBoymcP4VGZozYmsqQxY%2BfNkhAA%3D).

```
int foo() {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    return (***foo)() + foo();
}
```

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    push    rbx
    call    foo()
    mov     ebx, eax
    call    foo()
    add     eax, ebx
    mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: И зачем так много слов в стандарте, если на практике, увидев вызов по имени функции надо всегда генерить `call ...`? Конечно, если архитектура это поддерживает, ведь всегда можно придумать такую ISA, в которой call происходит только по регистру (или вершине стека ...). И в этом случае, независимо от слов в стандарте языка, адреса всех функций придется держать в памяти и загружать в регистр перед вызовом

Comment: @avp по-моему, вы сами ответили на вопрос — стандарт ничего не знает о `call` и на другой архитектуре может быть что-то другое. Реализации стараются зависеть от слов стандартов, чтобы им соответствовать. Стандарты стараются быть написаны так, чтобы не ограничивать реализации, чтобы им проще было соответствовать стандартам.

Comment: @avp _И зачем так много слов в стандарте_ Затем наверное, что к библиотечным функциям не стоит применять преобразование к указателю, когда они не помечены как addressable?

Answer (score 3):

Так как у вас функция статическая, компилятор при сборке находит заданный адрес функции `g` и в код заносит жёстко вызов по адресу.

```
адрес :
  код
  // возврат
  ret 

main :
  call адрес
```

*Разыменования для функций не требуется. Можно вызывать как указателем так и со звёздочкой.*

Comment: Компилятор не может знать адрес функции. Все что он знает (если компилирует вызываемую и вызывающую функции вместе) это смещение. Реальные исполнимые адреса становятся известны после обработки всех единиц компиляции (в т.ч. из всех библиотек) линкером (а в ряде случаев только после загрузки слинкованного модуля в память уже прямо перед его выполнением)